# Set custom World Origin in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I'm trying to set world origin anchor to some position that I want. Specifically, I want to be able to recognize an image and then, set the World Origin anchor (which is the device position when the app opens) to the center of that image.

I saw this documentation about ARConfiguration.WorldAlignment, which explains that you can set the WorldAligment to 3 specific cases. I have not found any documentation about how you can set the world origin to somewhere you like not being the device position.